# Повторное выполнение SQL запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Есть веб приложение на PHP + БД на MySQL. После выполнения какого-либо SQL запроса путем отправки данных через HTML форму, если обновить страницу, то SQL запрос выполняется снова, т.к. повторно отправляются данные в POST запросе. Это приводит к дублированию записей в БД.

Как можно этого избежать? Делать редирект через `header()` для каждой операции в браузере или есть другие решения?

Comment: *Как можно этого избежать?* Определитесь, чего Вы хотите избежать - повторной отправки запроса или дубликатов записей в БД?

Comment: редирект в целом - обычная практика. но есть и варианты отправки форм аяксом, и можно и флаг какой-нит сохранять в сессии о том, чтобы только единожды запрос выполнялся

Comment: проверять по базе на дубликаты, а потом пилить пост запрос

Comment: Вам необходимо часть скрипта которая принимает $_POST  вынести в другой файл php. Ссылку на скрипт с обработкой пост запроса пропишите в форме;
И в скрипте в конце добавьте пере направление страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делайте редирект.

Веб-приложение, это приложение, которое работает через HTTP-протокол. Это значит, что с приложением пользователь взаимодействует с помощью HTTP-запросов. Каждый раз когда ваш пользователь хочет чего-то от вашего приложения, он отправляет запрос.

Например, пользователь заполняет форму и отправляет в приложение данные для сохранения -- делает POST запрос на написанный вами обработчик. А что делает ваш обработчик? Он сохраняет данные в бд и внезапно передаёт пользователю HTML-документ! Получается он делает сразу два дела: сохраняет и выдаёт документ. Это довольно паршивый дизайн, пердставьте функцию в php, которая обновляет ваше имя в базе и заодно выводит список любимых фильмов -- довольно неудобно.

Чтобы всем было удобно, ваш обработчик должен на запрос сохранения данных сказать "я всё сохранил, можете полюбоваться результатами там-то". Это редирект. Такой ответ не содержит html-документ для пользователя, а только указывает где его посмотреть. Браузер пользователя сделает новый запрос автоматически и не даст пользователю повторять запрос на сохранение нажатием на обновление.

Потом можете добавить отправку форм javascript'ом. Схема не поменяется. Один обработчик -- один результат.

Answer (score 2):

Лучший вариант будет использовать [csrf token](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0) и редирект после обработки формы.

Если в кратце про csrf, то это работает так: При запросе страницы где расположена ваша форма, вы генерируете рандомную большую строку и куда-нибудь её записываете. Например в кэш. В форме добавляете hidden поле с именем `_csrf` (на самом деле может быть любое) и значением - ваша строка.

При получении данных из формы вы проверяете, что для этого пользователя вы генерировали строку и что пришедшая строка совпадает. И только тогда выполняете запись в базу. Кэш, конечно, подчищаете. Теперь если придет ещё один такой же запрос, он просто не пройдет. Дополнительно вы получите защиту от `csrf атак`.